# How would you pass data from a child view to a parent view using the iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Which method would you recommend to pass data from a child view back to it's parent view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this.

Set a member variable in the child when its added to the parent

Send a message to [self superview]

Use an NSNotification

There are others, too, of course, but these are the three I use most often.